__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript: exception in flutter with firebase_auth
I used verify Phone Number by firebase_auth in flutter and I have this exception in iOS devices:
flutter: -\[\__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:\]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600001755880

Flutter code:
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );



   await  FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(

        phoneNumber:  widget.phoneNumber,

        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential)async {
          p ('verificationCompleted*****************************************');
        },

        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
          p ('verificationFailed*****************************************');
          p (e.message);

        },

        codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken)async {
          p ('codeSent*****************************************');

        },

        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
          p ('codeAutoRetrievalTimeout*****************************************');
        
        },

      );

Firebase Packages (The latest versions):
  firebase_core: ^2.31.1
  firebase_messaging: ^14.9.3
  firebase_auth: ^4.19.6


  cloud_firestore: ^4.17.4

  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.1.2


platform :ios, '13.0'
AppDelegate.swift
import UIKit
import Flutter

import FirebaseCore




@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}


My Flutter doctor:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.6, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64, locale
    en-IQ)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.89.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!

I have updated all Firebase packages and still have this exception..
Are there any tips or solutions to this exception?

The other Firebase services all work properly in the app, I only have this problem with phone verification
